# Converting between MMBTU and MWh

Tags: energy, energy-efficiency, emissions

a quick question:

I want to convert between MMBTU and MWh to get at emission factors from energy.

I have the following information:

I use the data given in 40 CFR 98 (see [EPA source here](https://www.epa.gov/sites/default/files/2015-07/documents/emission-factors_2014.pdf)) by the EPA and gives me the Stationary Combustion Emission Factors by Energy content (in MMBTUs) for CO2, CH4 and N2O emissions. I convert the CH4 and N2O emissions using the global warming potentials (21 for CH4 and 310 for N20) to CO2eq.

This gives me 94.007 kgCO2eq/MMBTU for coal and 53.112 kgCO2eq/MMBTU  for natural gas.

Now that I have CO2eq emissions by a common unit of energy, I use the information I have on a kWh to convert this to kg CO2eq emissions by kWh. A kWh contains 3412 BTUs or 0.003412 MMBTUs of energy. Therefore, a kWh of coal produces 0.3207519 kg CO2eq and a kWh of gas produces 0.1812181 kg CO2eq. (or Therefore, a  coal produces 0.32  tCO2eq/MWh and a kWh of gas produces 0.181 tCO2eq/MWh ).

**BUT**: I have also found information, like [here](https://www.e-control.at/en/marktteilnehmer/oeko-energie/stromkennzeichnung/umweltauswirkungen) where I get values for a kWh of 0.882 tCO2eq/MWh for Coal or 0.440 tCO2eq/MWh for Gas. These two pieces of information clearly don't square up!!

In essence, I have the information that a country produced 9,028,638 MWh of Coal electricity. With an emission factor of e.g. 0.91 tCO2eq/MWh that would be 8.76 MtCO2eq. But using the other methodology, 9,028,638 MWh would be 28,369,254 MMBTUs and so would be 28,369,254 * (94.007/1000) = 2.6 MtCO2eq

So clearly using the two methodologies, I get two very different results - but I have no clue where I'm going wrong...

Is the emission factor just so different in individual cases?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your figures look OK to me for heat energy. Now factor in the thermal efficiency of electricity generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, the difference is that you are trying to compare different things. I'll try to sum it up in the following table:

|  | coal | gas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EPA | 0.32 tCO2eq/MWh | 0.181 tCO2eq/MWh |
| e-control | 0.880 tCO2eq/MWh | 0.440 tCO2eq/MWh |
| ratio of EPA to e-control | 0.36 | 0.41 |

It appears to me that when you are using the data in the EPA report you are considering the *[primary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_energy)* energy content (so its MWh of primary energy).

However, the values from the e-control report consider MWh of electricity generation. Therefore in order to produce 1 MWh of electricity you need to consume about 2.5 to 4 MWh of primary energy depending on the type of fuel and the efficiency of the generator.

---

Although there is variability in the efficiency, the interpretation above is supported by the following data:

- According to [this](http://needtoknow.nas.edu/energy/energy-sources/fossil-fuels/natural-gas/#:%7E:text=A%20gas%2Dfired%20plant%20was,as%20much%20as%2060%25%20efficient.) the efficiency of gas fired electrical generators is about 42%, and coal is about 33%.
- According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_fuel_power_station#:%7E:text=Typical%20thermal%20efficiency%20for%20utility,(i.e.%20temperatures%20too%20low.)) the efficiency of coal electrical generators is about 37%. (In "Basic concepts: heat into mechanical energy" it states *Typical thermal efficiency for utility-scale electrical generators is around 37% for coal and oil-fired plants*)

Comment: This is the answer. The e-control site cites a source titled "Emission factors for labelling of electricity generated."

Comment: Awesome NMech, thanks so much!